# How to take an rvalue reference parameter and pass it on elsewhere?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am a reasonably competent C++ user (not a complete noob). I have a class that acts as a resource handle.  It makes sense for the class to have a move constructor and for the copy construtor to be deleted:

```
struct Foo {

  Foo (int i) : // For sake of example.
    x(i)
  {}

  Foo (Foo && f) :
    x(f.x)
  {
    f.x = 0; // 0 is special and means "moved from".
  }

  Foo (const Foo & f) = delete;

private:
  int x;
};
```

I've been doing this in a cargo-cult fashion for ages now and it works fine.  Now I'm trying to step up a gear with my C++11 usage.

I have another class that keeps a `vector` of `Foo`:

```
struct Bar { // (Constructor added below)
  std::vector<Foo> foos;
};
```

I'd like to write a constructor for `Bar` where the caller passes in a `vector<Foo>`.  I'd like the *entire vector* that the caller provides to be moved into `Bar.foos`.  I want to make that explicit to the caller by making the constructor parameter a `vector<Foo>&&` rather than a plain `vector<Foo>&`.  That way, the caller must `std::move` the vector in to the constructor.

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{     
    Foo f1 (1);
    Foo f2 (2);
    std::vector<Foo> v;
    v.push_back (std::move(f1));
    v.push_back (std::move(f2));

    Bar b (std::move(v)); // I want the user to HAVE TO std::move v.
    return 0;
}
```

I naively tried writing `Bar` constructor like this:

```
struct Bar {

  Bar (vector<Foo> && vf) :
    foos (vf) // pass the rvalue reference into foos' constructor, right?
  {}

  std::vector<Foo> foos;
};
```

My computer has g++ 4.9.2 and clang++ 3.5.0 and they both give me a small explosion of errors.  They're both trying to construct `Bar.foos` using the vector *copy constructor*, which then fails because I've deleted the copy constructor of `Foo`.

How can I give 'vf', the rvalue reference of `vector<Foo>` straight to the constructor of 'foos'?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It could work, but this is not what it's meant for. `std::forward` is meant for when you don't know at the call site whether to pass as an lvalue or as an rvalue. `std::move`, as in Pete Becker's answer, always passes as an rvalue, which is more appropriate here since that's the goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A named argument is not an rvalue, so you have to convert `vf` to an rvalue reference by calling `std::move`:

```
Bar(std::vector<Foo>&& vf) : foos(std::move(vf) {}
```

Also, it's not quite correct to say that the user **must** call `std::move` for an rvalue parameter; there's no need for `std::move` when the argument is the return value of a function, which is the classic notion of an rvalue.

Comment: Yes, I suppose what I meant to say was that I just need the caller to *be aware* that their vector parameter is going to be moved from.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when you have a parameter of move-only type, you take it by value:

```
struct Bar
{
    std::vector<Foo> foos;

    Bar(vector<Foo> vf) :
        foos(std::move(vf)a) {}
};
```

This forces the caller to write

```
Bar x(std::move(y));
```

which makes clear that ownership of `y` is relinquished.
In addition, the caller can just pass the return value of a function without further ado:

```
Bar x(get_me_some_Foos());
```